# How to add Automated UI Tests into Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, automated-tests, mstest

I have couple Automated UI tests that i can work with with my VS2010 Ultimate version.

At other pc i have VS2010 Professional. I would like to create coded UI tests in this version.

Is there some way how i can create Coded UI tests in VS2010 Professional?

Also i need it to run with TFS and Automated builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As show in this [Visual Studio 2010 comparison chart](http://www.softwaremedia.com/software-guides/visual-studio-2010-edition-comparison.html), Coded UI Tests are **not** available in VS2010 professional. You will have to upgrade to Premium or Ultimate.